# Don't prevent default action in Electron using globalShortcut

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I use

```
var globalShortcut = require('electron').globalShortcut;
```

For open application window after key press

```
var ret = globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+X', function() {
  console.log('CommandOrControl+X is pressed')
  mainWindow.show();
})
```

But default event disabled now, can i add my event without disabling default event?

Comment: do you want to conservate both actions?

Comment: yep
for example: i want to cut the text and open mainWindow in this case.

Comment: uhm i think maybe can do it with a js library. by example in angularjs i use hotkeys and this don't override my electron shortcuts.but many times they collide

Comment: @artofatih Have you been able to figure out a solution? I am facing the same issue. I don't want to swallow the events, since it breaks keyboard events of other applications

Comment: @dc10 No, had to write a module in C

Comment: Is there still no solution for this?